# Infinite product with alternating terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

I would like to know that for what real value of $p$, the infinite product
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{i (-1)^n}{n^p} \right)$$
converges.

I only know that $\prod z_n$ converges if and only if $\sum \log z_n$ converges if $\Re z_n > 0$. It looks like the alternating series for me, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Also, can the convergence series tests in the real case (e.g, comparison test, integral test,...) be applied to complex series?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an alternating series, but rather alternating perturbations to $1$.  So, applying the logarithm is actually a sensible step: for small $|x|$, one has
$$
\ln(1 + x) \doteq x
$$

Comment: @user8960 with your argument one could think it converges for $Re(p) > 0$, whereas it does only for $Re(p) > 1/2$. Look at $(1-\frac{a}{n^p})(1+\frac{a}{(n+1)^p}) = 1-\frac{a^2}{n^p (n+1)^p}+a((n+1)^{-p}-n^{-p}) =1-\frac{a^2}{n^{2p}}+\mathcal{O}(n^{-p-1})$ so $\log \prod_{n \ge 1} (1+(-1)^n \frac{a}{n^p}) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \log (1-\frac{a^2}{(4n)^{2p}}+ \mathcal{O}(n^{-p-1})) = -\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a^2}{(2n)^{2p}}+ \mathcal{O}(n^{-p-1})$ converges only for $Re(p) > 1/2$

Comment: I didn't make any argument.  Just indicated what I would try.  That's why it was a comment, not an answer.  I don't think my comment implies convergence for $\Re(p) > 0$: one has to worry about the error terms in the approximation I wrote.

Comment: And I used that $n^{-s} - (n+1)^{-s} = \int_n^{n+1} s x^{-s-1}dx = \mathcal{O}(n^{-s-1})$ which is the best method for showing $\eta(s) = \sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ converges for $Re(s) >0$  @user8960